# Is Dijkstra's algorithm most efficient for computing single-source shortest path?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, dijkstra

Is Dijkstra's algorithm for finding single-source shortest path the most efficient one for an undirected graph? I am using this algorithm to compute the minimum fare for a bus route from station 1 (start node) to station N (destination node). The paths connecting intermediate stations have a fare assigned(edge weight).Note, the bus route network can have

- 1<=Stations<=50000
- 1<=Routes<=500000

The details of the problem can be found here -
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/jack-goes-to-rapture

Now,the logic of my code is sound as only 2 out of 16 test cases have failed.The reason for failure is that graph sizes in the test cases being huge, execution time is causing timeout.

I could use some help in optimizing the code(Dijkstra's algorithm). if there are other algorithms that could be more efficient for graphs of large sizes, would like to know about it as well.Thanks.

Comment: [A* search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) might be faster?

Comment: If you have good heuristic function, maybe A* is better https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Comment: Look up A-star with Landmarks and Triangle Inequality, also known by the acronym *ALT path-finding*.

Comment: Look up A-star with Landmarks and Triangle Inequality, also known by the acronym ALT path-finding. This will explain how to build and use a suitable (ie admissible) heuristic in order to achieve your performance requirement. Dijkstra's algorithm is often O(N^2) performance.

Comment: The complexity Dijkstra's algorithm `O(E log V)` with the "standard" implementation (with a priority queue). You may also look at the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_Path_Faster_Algorithm

Comment: Did you use Fibonacci Heap Algorithm in your Dijkstra Algorithm ? It can reduce the complexity from O(E log V) into O(E + V log V).

Comment: actually this problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/jack-goes-to-rapture can be simply solved using traditional Dijkstra algorithm. I just submited my answer in c++ with all positive results and the maximum running time is around 1s.

Comment: I tried solving in java using traditional Dijkstra but I got timeout on test cases 15 & 16. I saw the input of 15. It's huge hence posted this question

Comment: The way the edge weights accumulate is not quite the same as the usual shortest path problem, but Dijkstra's algorithm still works, and is plenty fast for the given problem sizes.  You have a mistake in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can a queue to priority queue to optimize it.

Check the code below

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define mod 1000000000000
using namespace std;

typedef long long int ll;
typedef long double ld;

vector<ll> pred1,pred2;
vector<ll> dist1,dist2;
vector<ll> vis1,vis2;
vector< pair<ll,ll> > v[100005];

class compare{

public:
    bool operator()(pair<ll,ll> x,pair<ll,ll> y)
    {
        return x.second>y.second;
    }
};

bool cmp(ll x,ll y)
{
    return x>y;
}

int main()
{
    ll n,k,x,y,d;
    cin>>n>>k;
    pred1.clear();
    dist1.clear();
    vis1.clear();
    dist1.resize(n+5);
    vis1.resize(n+5);
    pred1.resize(n+5);
    for(ll i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        dist1[i]=mod;
        pred1[i]=0;
        v[i].clear();
    }
    for(ll i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        cin>>x>>y>>d;
        v[x].push_back(make_pair(y,d));
        v[y].push_back(make_pair(x,d));
    }
    ll a,b;
    a=1;
    b=n;
    dist1[a]=0;
    priority_queue< pair<ll,ll> , vector< pair<ll,ll> > , compare > q;
    pair<ll,ll> p={a,0};
    q.push(p);
    while(q.size()!=0)
    {
        p=q.top();
        q.pop();
        if(vis1[p.first]==true)
            continue;
        vis1[p.first]=true;
        ll idx=p.first;
        for(ll i=0;i<v[idx].size();i++)
        {
            if(dist1[v[idx][i].first]>dist1[idx]+( (v[idx][i].second-dist1[idx]>=0) ? (v[idx][i].second-dist1[idx]) : 0 ) )
            {
                dist1[v[idx][i].first]=dist1[idx]+( (v[idx][i].second-dist1[idx]>=0) ? (v[idx][i].second-dist1[idx]) : 0 );
                q.push(make_pair(v[idx][i].first,dist1[v[idx][i].first]));
                pred1[v[idx][i].first]=idx;
            }
        }
    }
    if(dist1[b]==mod)
    {
        cout<<"NO PATH EXISTS\n";
        return 0;
    }
    cout<<dist1[b]<<"\n";

return 0;
}
```